# ipcRenderer not receiving messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm trying to send a message when the 'q' key is pressed from my `index.js` file to the script on `index.html`, but I don't really know why It's not working properly.

Here is my js file

```
const url = require('url');
const path = require('path');

const {app, BrowserWindow, globalShortcut, ipcMain, webContents} = require('electron');
let mainWindow;

app.on('ready', function(){
    // Create new window
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
      backgroundColor: '#000000',
      fullscreen : true, 
      frame : false,
      icon : __dirname + "/res/icon.jpg",
      webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration : true
      }
    });
    // Load html in window
    mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
      pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
      protocol: 'file:',
      slashes:true
    }))
    globalShortcut.register('Esc', () => {
        app.quit();
    });
    globalShortcut.register('q', () => {
      leftLight();

  });

});

function leftLight() {
  mainWindow && mainWindow.webContents.send('key-pressed-q');
  console.log("Sending q pressed to html...");
}
```

And the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class = rect_green> <h2 class=blocktext >LEFT FENCER</h2></div>
    <div class = rect_red><h2 class=blocktext> RIGHT FENCER</h2> </div>
    <div class = crono> <h2 class=crontext>3:00</h2></div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
        var ipc = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
        ipc.on('key-pressed-q', (e) => {
            //var element =  document.getElementsByClassName("rect_green");
            //element.style["background-color"] = "yellow";
            console.log("q pressed in html file");    
        });
    </script>

</html>
```

The key pressed is detected, but the message is not received by the ipcRenderer. Any mistakes on my code?

Comment: Do you get any error in the renderer process console?

Comment: Hi, if any of the answers below have helped you feel free to upvote and accept it :)

Comment: @Mike Neither of them helped, but, restarting Visual Code without making any changes to the code solved it. Im clueless why.

Comment: Why do you think it's not working? Have you checked _your devtools console_ for the message? (works for me)

Comment: @pergy I closed and open VSC and suddenly it started to get the messages. I'm really surprised, because the file was saved. I think sometimes just rebooting everything works...

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you've got the syntax of `.webContents.send(` wrong.

You need to provide a channel for your message, E.g. `.webContents.send('channel', 'msg')`, then you listen for that channel in your page.

A channel can be whatever you want. For example:

Electron js file:

```
mainWindow.webContents.send('channelNameCanBeAnything', 'key-pressed-q');
```

Html file:

```
ipc.on('channelNameCanBeAnything', (msgStr) => {
    console.log("q pressed in html file");
    console.log(msgStr); // Will output 'key-pressed-q'.
});
```

[See the docs](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentssendchannel-args)